# How to get the last value emit from vue event bus?

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue event bus, for example in resize window:

resize.ts:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const windowResize = new Vue();
```

when I emit value:

```
 const innerWidth = …;
 const innerHeight = …;
 resize.$emit('resize', { innerWidth, innerHeight });
```

when I received value:

```
 resize.$on('resize', ({ innerWidth, innerHeight }) => { … });
```

My question is it possible to get the get **the last value** has been dispatched?

for example say in lazy component I want to have the width and height that calculate in the parents components? I think something like `subject` behavior (not `BehaviorSubject`) in rxjs…
In this lazy component I want to write

```
resize.$on('resize', ({ innerWidth, innerHeight }) => { … });
```

but I don't want to trigger the resize event.

Comment: `$on`'s listener is invoked only when you `$emit` the event mapped to it.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but is there the option to get the last value in vue?

Comment: may b, you can maintain an additional state & assign the last value to it every time the listener is invoked.

Comment: Yes it's certainly possible by writing some Javascript logic, but there is nothing built into Vue for this purpose

Comment: You want to do some computation on `innerWidth, innerHeight` before triggerring `resize`?